# Using gon with jasmine-rails

Tags: testing, backbone.js, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Our backbone app uses [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon).  When we try to run our tests, we are getting a `gon is undefined` error in the console of the browser.  Our layout file includes a call to `include_gon`, but that file is not being loaded by jasmine, so jasmine is failing in our first javascript file that contains gon.  We tried creating a helper to assign the `gon` variable to an empty hash (like a fixture), but the helper was called after the first call to gon and therefore didn't fix our issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secret was to use the asset pipeline to define the load order of my files. I commented out these lines from `jasmine.yml`

```
# path to parent directory of src_files
# relative path from Rails.root
# defaults to app/assets/javascripts
#src_dir: "app/assets/javascripts"

# list of file expressions to include as source files
# relative path from src_dir
#src_files:
#  - "application.{js.coffee,js,coffee}"
```

And created `spec.js.coffee` with these lines:

```
#= require application
#= require jasmine-jquery
```

Now my js files get loaded in order and I am good to go.

Comment: Curious... can you explain a bit further about how this fixed your issue? I'm not seeing a connection... because the `include_gon` is called from the `application.html.erb` file, not from `application.js` right? so why would requiring the `application.js` file have solved your problem? wondering because i'm running into the same issue, and this isn't solving it

Comment: It's been a couple years since I did this, but I think it was about load ORDER. The specs loaded the js files in a different order (that is, they loaded the test before the gon js file), so therefore when a call was made to gon, the gon file hadn't been loaded and gon was undefined.  I think by manually stating load order, I was sure that application.js (with gon defined) gets called before jsamine-jquery (which called gon)

Comment: i guess in my experience i found a different problem entirely, which is that the statement that defines `gon` in any JS file is `include_gon` which is called from `application.html.erb`, which there is no way to call in an order before any JS loads. That's why I'm having trouble...

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to define `window.gon = {}` inside the test like so:

```
describe("A suite is just a function", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    window.gon = {}
    gon.test = "this"
  })
  it ("should find gon", function() {
    expect(gon.test).toBe("this")
  })
})
```